# Prove that if $S$ is a partition of $A$ and $E_S$ is the corresponding equivalence, then $A/E_S = S$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Studying with the book Introduction to Set Theory by Karel Hrbacek, I encountered this proposition:

If $S$ is a partition of $A$ and $E_S$ is the corresponding equivalence, then $A/E_S = S$.

Where

$$E_S=\{\left \langle a,b \right \rangle \in A \times A : (\exists C \in S)(a,b \in C)\}$$
$$A/E_S = \{[a]_{E_S} : a \in A \}  $$

I tried to do the proof, but would like to know if the first part is correctly done. Also, regarding the second part, I wonder if it is possible to conclude $X=C$. I have thought of something different like: ... by reflexivity we know that $a \space E_S \space a$ iff $a \in X$, so it must follow that $X \in S$. But I have doubts whether or not this is a correct reasoning. Any help is appreciated.

***Proof***. Assume $S$ is a partition of $A$ and $E_S$ is its corresponding equivalence.

($\subseteq$). Let $X \in S$. Then $X$ is a non-empty subset of $A$, so $a \in X$ for some $a \in A$. Hence $a \space E_S \space a$, so it follows that $a \in [a]_{E_S}$, which means $X \subseteq [a]_{E_S}$. Therefore $X$ is an equivalence class modulo $E_S$. Consequently $X \in A/E_S$.

($\supseteq $). Let $X \in A/E_S$. Then $X$ is an equivalence class modulo $E_S$. Hence $X=[a]_{E_S}$ for some $a \in A$, by reflexivity we know that $a \space E_S \space a$, so $a \in X$. But also $a \space E_S \space a$, implies there exists some $C \in S$ for which $a \in C$ holds. ...

Comment: For part 1, show everything that is $E_S$-related to $a$ is also in $X$. This is the reverse direction $X\supseteq [a]_{E_S}$. For part 2, I would say: suppose $X=[a]_{E_S}$, then we know every element of $X$ is $E_S$-related to $a$. So $\forall b\in X: b E_S a$ implies $\exists C\in S$ with $(b\in C)$ in particular, by the set definition. This gives $X\subseteq C$. This gives us the reverse direction as well, since for any $c\in C$ and $x\in X\subseteq C$, we have $c E_S x$. Since $X$ is an equivalence class, it contains everything related to its members, namely $c\in X$. Hence $C\subseteq X$

Answer (score 1):

*[Update: nullified but good as a side note?]*
Alternatively, one could show the map:
$$f: S\to A/E_S;$$
$$X\mapsto [x]_{E_S}$$
for $x\in X\in S$
is well-defined and bijective.

---

$\underline{\text{Well-Definition:}}$
If $x_1,x_2\in X$, it should be clear that $[x_1]_{E_S}=[x_2]_{E_S}$.
$\underline{\text{Injective:}}$
Suppose for $X,Y\in S$ that $f(X)=f(Y).$ Then we have for representative elements $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$ that $[x]_{E_S} = [y]_{E_S}$. Hence $x E_S y$ and $\exists C\in S$ containing both $x,y$. Arbitrariness yields $X,Y\subseteq C$. But this contradicts $S$ being a partition, unless $X=C=Y$. Recall a partition of $A$ consists of mutually disjoint, non-empty subsets of $A$. Basically $C$ is not disjoint from $X$ and likewise for $Y$, so they must be the same.
$\underline{\text{Surjective:}}$
Let $[a]_{E_S}\in A/E_S$ be given. Since $A= \coprod\limits_{X\in S}X$, we have $\exists X'\in S$ containing $a$. So that $[a]_{E_S}=f(X')$.

---

Therefore $S \cong A/E_S$ as Sets.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But there is something that confuses me. Aren't you showing that these two sets are equal in the sense of cardinality with the map $f$, but how does this implies that they are equal in the sense that they have the same elements?

Comment: So the problem is with the symbol in the last line it seems. I showed the sets were in 1-1 correspondence, but I didn't show they are the same elements. The continuation of your proof does though, through dual inclusion. I think a good c.x. in this case is to apply a permutation to the powerset, $\mathscr{P}(A)$, and keep track of $S$. Then we may obtain a different subset of $\mathscr{P}(A)$ that is in 1-1 correspondence with $S$ (even with elements of the same universe), that is not equal to $S$.